# Headline shown one page too late

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, header-footer

I have a problem with the TOC.

Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,bibtotoc,idxtotoc,headsepline,footsepline,footexclude,BCOR12mm,DIV13,openany]{scrbook}
% Included by MAIN.TEX
% Defines the settings for the CAMP report document

\renewcommand{\sectfont}{\normalfont \bfseries}        % Schriftart der Kopfzeile

% manipulate footer
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ifoot[\footertext]{\footertext} % \footertext set in INFO.TEX
%\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont\rmfamily}

%% allow sophisticated control structures
\usepackage{ifthen}

% use Palatino as default font
\usepackage{palatino}

% enable special PostScript fonts
\usepackage{pifont}

% make thumbnails
\usepackage{thumbpdf}

%to use the subfigures
\usepackage{subfigure}


\usepackage{colortbl}


%% show program code\ldots
%\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage{program}

\usepackage{multirow}

%% use colors
\usepackage{color}

%% make fancy math
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{yhmath} % für die adots 
%% mark text as preliminary
%\usepackage[draft,german,scrtime]{prelim2e}

%% create an index
\usepackage{makeidx}

% for the program environment
\usepackage{float}

%% load german babel package for german abstract
%\usepackage[german,american]{babel}
\usepackage[german,english]{babel}
\selectlanguage{german}

% use german characters as well
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}       % allow Latin1 characters

% use initals dropped caps - doesn't work with PDF
\usepackage{dropping}


\usepackage{styles/shortoverview}
%----------------------------------------------------
%      Graphics and Hyperlinks
%----------------------------------------------------

%% check for pdfTeX
\ifx\pdftexversion\undefined
 %% use PostScript graphics
 \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
 \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps,.epsi}
 \graphicspath{{figures/}{figures/review}} 
 %% allow rotations
 \usepackage{rotating}
 %% mark pages as draft copies
 %\usepackage[english,all,light]{draftcopy}
 %% use hypertex version of hyperref
 \usepackage[hypertex,hyperindex=false,colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\else %% reduce output size \pdfcompresslevel=9
 %% declare pdfinfo
 %\pdfinfo { 
 %  /Title (my title) 
 %  /Creator (pdfLaTeX) 
 %  /Author (my name) 
 %  /Subject (my subject    ) 
 %  /Keywords (my keywords)
 %}
 %% use pdf or jpg graphics
 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
 \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg,.JPG,.png,.pdf,.eps}
 \graphicspath{{figures/}} 

 %% Load float package, for enabling floating extensions
 \usepackage{float}

 %% allow rotations
 \usepackage{rotating}
 %% use pdftex version of hyperref
 \usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red,citecolor=red,%
 anchorcolor=red,urlcolor=red,bookmarks=true,%
 bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=0,plainpages=false%
 bookmarksnumbered=true,hyperindex=false,pdfstartview=%
 ]{hyperref}
%
%\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks=false,linkcolor=red,citecolor=red,%
% anchorcolor=red,urlcolor=red,bookmarks=true,%
% bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=0,plainpages=false%
% bookmarksnumbered=true,hyperindex=false,pdfstartview=%
% ]{hyperref}
\fi


%% Fancy chapters
%\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
%\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
%\usepackage[Bjarne]{fncychap}

%\usepackage[avantgarde]{quotchap}

% set the bibliography style
%\bibliographystyle{styles/bauermaNum}
%\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliographystyle{plain}


\begin{document}
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

  \vspace*{2cm}
  \begin{center}
  {\Large \bf Abstract}
  \end{center}
  \vspace{1cm}
  Text text text
  \clearpage
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Content}
  \tableofcontents
  \clearpage
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Outline of Thesis}

  \begin{center}
    \huge{Outline of Thesis}
  \end{center}
  text text text
\end{document}
```

My problem is that I got the TOC headline on the next Page in the top of the outline of my Thesis. Anybody got an idea?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Please try to add a fully functional [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). This one does not even compile. What is `\phantomsection`?

Comment: after the `\clearpage`, add the command `\markboth{}{}` to wipe out all running heads.  until a new chapter or section is issued, running heads will not be reset automatically,

Comment: I put the hole header in here. Because I can't explain what the `\phantomsection` means. If it helps, I use pdflatex on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. 

The second posting helps a little bit. Now I didn't got any Headline, also not in top of the TOC.

Comment: @masu `\phantomsection` is a command from the `hyperref` package.

Comment: @jfbu I know that. That was only a figure of speech. :)

Comment: `\footertext set in INFO.TEX` so we can't compile as we don't have this `INFO.TEX`. (and on my current system, I don't have `droppings` either and some other things). You should first spend some time removing packages and see if and when this removes what you perceive as a problem.

Comment: @fklausen That's the point of constructing a minimal working example. I didn't need an explanation for the `\phantomsection` just a `\usepackage{hyperref}`. Or (in this case it seems to be more appropriate) you should remove these commands from the example if the problem occurs even without them. A useful MWE is crucial, you'll have higher possibility of a good answer if you have a MINIMAL example demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As Barbara mentioned in a comment, running headers aren't cleared automatically. You need to issue a `\cleardoublepage` and after that use `\markboth{}{}`

You seem to be setting sectioning commands by hand, which is never a good idea. Using the KOMA-built in commands, you can achieve your goals in a much easier way. You can read more about it at [Correct use of hyperref and addcontentsline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193799/37907)

Please not, that i substituted the obsolete options for the current KOMA-options.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,
%bibtotoc,
bibliography=totoc,
%idxtotoc,Not supported
headsepline,
footsepline,
%footexclude,
footinclude=false,
%BCOR12mm,
BCOR=12mm,
%DIV13,
DIV=13,
openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[german,english]{babel}
\selectlanguage{german}%Really the old german spelling?
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addchap{Outline of Thesis}
\blindtext[12]
\foreach \x in {1,...,20} {\blinddocument};
\end{document}
```