# How to use unnumbered chapters with KOMA-script?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, koma-script, links

I am having some issues with the hyperref package. I would like to create a Introduction chapter without a number so I use `\chapter*{Introduction}` and `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}` because I want it in the table of contents (see example).

But then the link in my PDF viewer gets it wrong and also the automatically created header is no longer correct (see picture). The table of contents shows the right page number (p.1) but the link is also wrong.

What is my mistake here?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{glossaries}
  \makeglossaries

\newacronym{eg}{e.g.}{%
for example
}


\begin{document}


\frontmatter

% abstract before the table of contents
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\blindtext

\tableofcontents

% chapter with acronyms
\cleardoublepage \phantomsection 
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glossary}

\cleardoublepage
\mainmatter


\phantomsection
% \chapter{Introduction} % with this everything is correct but I don't want the number
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

\blindtext

\pagebreak

\blindtext

% first chapter
\chapter{Chapter1}

\gls{eg}
\blindtext

\pagebreak

\blindtext


\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Looking for `addchap`?

Comment: See also [One chapter without numeration](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22907)

Comment: Seems like I do ;). Thanks a lot. 
Should \addcontentsline not be used in the KOMA-Scripts or what is the problem here?

Comment: You can use `\addcontentsline` but you have to take care of all the rest yourself. KOMA takes care of it with `\addchap` so it is reallly useful.

Comment: It should be noted that    \hyperref redefines the    \contentsline macro to use 4 args instead of 3.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

KOMA-Script provides very powerful commands for almost every
possible situation. As you noticed, the headers were showing
the previous chapter and hyperlinks didn't work properly when
using `\chapter*` along with `addcontentsline`.

The command `\addchap` takes care of this. It adds the
unnumbered chapter to the table of contents, it sets `\markboth`
accordingly. Additionally it makes sure that hyperlinks are set the right
way, it even ensures, that there is the small *chapter gap* in
the list of figures and list of tables.

If, for some reason, you want a different toc-entry, just use the
optional command like you are used to.

If you want the unnumbered chapters to be indented as if there were a number, use the documentclass option `toc=indentunnumbered`. This will have an effect on *every* chapter that has been set with the documented `addxcontentsline` (or any higher-level) command. Of course, using `\addchap` is the way to go.

There is a starred
variant as well which does not create a toc-entry and clears the head. This way, the header of the previous chapter is gone.

Commands to be used for unnumbered sections are provided as well, those are `\addsec` (with its optional argument) and `\addsec*`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\filler}{\blindtext[7]}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{addchap}
\filler
\addchap[ToC entry]{Heading?}
\filler
\chapter{Chapter}
\filler
\addchap*{No ToC Entry, header cleared}
\filler
\end{document}
```

The standard classes do not provide those commands, but one can easily implement the basic funtionality as is described in [How to deal with unnumbered chapters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199086/37907)

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out by Johannes_B in the comments using

```
\addchap{Introduction}
```

instead of

```
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
```

solves the problem.

Comment: i am just writing up an own anwer, with some explanations ;-)

Comment: Okay thx. I can accept it only in two days anyway ;)