# Book(standard class), headings for chapter* sections not all caps - urgent help needed

Tags: header-footer, lyx

I have a 400 page document in Lyx 2.1, `book`(standard class), using default settings. The `\chapter` headings appear in all caps in the header, but the `\chapter*` headings (which I manually add to the TOC and including headings using `\markboth`) appear as normal italic lowercase. Is there a simple way of making them both the same?

I do know that the `fancyhdr` (or something similar) package was invented for this purpose, but the book is going for printing tomorrow (large commercial publisher) and I cannot risk any major change as it has already been proof-read. I would like to simple change the few headings that need to be changed without any reformatting.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `\markboth{\MakeUppercase <leftmark>}{\MakeUppercase <rightmark>}` or something the like, not tested, because missing [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that will add a running header to *all* unnumbered chapters, so handle with care. It uses package `etoolbox` to prepend the `markboth` command you would do manually.  **Be careful, this code is bound to fail.** Best to set the headers manually.

Just to point that out, the right way to uppercase something is to use `\MakeUppercase{<content>}`.

Btw: A KOMA-class has it's own commands to take care of things like that. I once summed it up in [Correct use of hyperref and addcontentsline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193799/37907). There are other tripwires one can hit.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
%The following adds a running header for ALL unnumbered chapters
\pretocmd{\@schapter}{%pre
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}%
\typeout{Are your sure you want to mark a head here?}%
}{\typeout{Succes}
}{%Fail
\typeout{FAIL}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{a numbered chapter}
\blindtext[10]
\section{a section}
\blindtext[10]
\chapter*{an unnumbered chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{a unnumbered chapter}
\blindtext[10]
\section{a section}
\blindtext[10]
\chapter*{another unnumbered chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{another unnumbered chapter}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer pdf doc "Page Layout in Latex" written by Piet van Oostrum. He says if you want get your chapter headings in Uppercases you have to use the following command

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{%
\chaptername\ \thechapter.%
\ #1}}{}}
```

in the preamable after the line `\pagestyle{fancy}`

Default:
The header text is turned into all uppercase in `book.cls`

As per Leslie Lamport book style you must have used the following in preamble
`\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}` just to eliminate chapter numbers and the uppercaseness. Make it a comment and add the above said command to get the chapter title in capital letters. 
a

Comment: The OP clearly states that `fancyhdr` isn't used. I think there will be no line `\pagestyle{fancy}`.

Comment: Be careful, chaptermark will typeset the number (counter) of `\thechapter`. Since an unnumbered chapter doesn't have a number (and hence no `refstepcounter` occurs) the number of the previous Chap will be typeset. This will be confusing.