# section header with markboth

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, classicthesis

I have used `\markboth` to specify specific text in certain sections of my document. Now in the middle part of the documents (the real chapters), I want to chapter name left and the section name right. I used `\chaptermark`, but intro keeps showing. I want to keep this as simple as possible and just use markboth if possible, it would seem I am doing something simple wrong...

```
\documentclass[parskip=half,10pt,twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[dottedtoc, floatperchapter, parts]{classicthesis}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\tocEntry{Introduction}}
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Introduction}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Introduction}}

\chapter[Short title]{Full title}
 \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}

\end{document}
```

I managed to print the chapter number + title on the left with the following command. Now I just need the section number + title on the right.

```
 \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\chaptername}\ \spacedlowsmallcaps{\thechapter}.\ #1}{}}
```

I have tried \markrigth but that does not work. Any ideas? I am sure this is pretty simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct use of hyperref and addcontentsline](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193799)

Comment: `\markboth{\leftmark}{\rightmark}`

Comment: That was the first one I tried, but it keeps showing introduction.

Comment: Because `\chapter` does not update using markboth. But since you want an unnumbered chapter *and* a toc entry *and* updated headers; use the proper command `\addchap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code fixed it for me. Be sure to put this before you first chapter title occurs.

```
 \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\chaptername}\ \spacedlowsmallcaps{\thechapter}.\ #1}{}}

 \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\thesection}.\ \spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{} }
```