# Missing pagenumber in bookmarks

Tags: table-of-contents, bookmarks

The pagenumber from "Inhaltsverzeichnis" is missing in the bookmarks.

I manually added the Inhaltsverzeichnis (TOC) with

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
```

but it doesn't print the pagenumber. The LOF or LOT, which I added with the same command, appear as I wish.

[image: Missing page number for pdfbookmark]

When I add

```
\pdfbookmark{Inhaltsverzeichnis}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
```

instead of \addcontentsline, I get what I want in the bookmarks but the TOC disappears from the TOC.

[image: Missing "Inhaltsverzeichnis" in TOC]

How to fix that?

**UPDATE**

Here's the MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     % deutsche Worttrennung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Ausgabe von Sonderzeichen und Akzenten in PDF verbessert
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Eingabe von Sonderzeichen möglich
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}     % subsubsections nummerieren
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}        % subsubsections in TOC

\usepackage[ %
    pdfproducer={Texmaker},     % 
    pdfcreator={pdfLaTeX},      % 
    hidelinks,                  % versteckt die Boxen um die Links in der PDF
    bookmarksnumbered,          % nummereiert Lesezeichen
    ]{hyperref}                 % PDF Metainformationen hinzufügen 

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\chapter*{Sperrvermerk}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Sperrvermerk}
\lipsum[1]
\clearpage

\chapter*{Vorwort}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Vorwort}
\lipsum[2]
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\pagestyle{headings}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}
\lipsum[3]
\section{One.1}
\lipsum[4]
\section{One.2}
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\addcontentsline` adds the bookmark automatically. `\pdfbookmark` will not add an entry to the Toc however. Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Bookmarks do not show pagenumbers, normally

Comment: Are you using a KOMA class? There is a much simple and safer way: `\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}` But ask yourself, why it is not put there by default.

Comment: It seems you like to get yourself into trouble. [Correct use of hyperref and addcontentsline](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193799)

Comment: Indeed, setuptoc did it. Didn't know that command until now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long there is no MWE, I assume `book.cls`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\phantomsection
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}%
\chapter{First}
\section{First}

\end{document}
```

### Another solution for the MWE

Use `\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}` in the preamble and remove the line `\addcontentsline` for the contents. It will appear otherwise again.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     % deutsche Worttrennung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Ausgabe von Sonderzeichen und Akzenten in PDF verbessert
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Eingabe von Sonderzeichen möglich
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}     % subsubsections nummerieren
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}        % subsubsections in TOC

\usepackage[ %
    pdfproducer={Texmaker},     % 
    pdfcreator={pdfLaTeX},      % 
    hidelinks,                  % versteckt die Boxen um die Links in der PDF
    bookmarksnumbered,          % nummereiert Lesezeichen
    ]{hyperref}                 % PDF Metainformationen hinzufügen 

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\chapter*{Sperrvermerk}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Sperrvermerk}
\lipsum[1]
\clearpage

\chapter*{Vorwort}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Vorwort}
\lipsum[2]
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\pagestyle{headings}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}
\lipsum[3]
\section{One.1}
\lipsum[4]
\section{One.2}
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: you're the man, thanks! setuptoc did the magic..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using KOMA-Book (scrbook) and after providing a wrong solution (duplicate entries in pdf bookmarks, see my first answer), I googled a bit and found a [solution](http://www.komascript.de/comment/4216#comment-4216) for your problem. `\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}` is what you need. After compiling the document three times, everything should be fine:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\title{foobar}
\maketitle

\chapter{Before TOC 1}
\Blindtext

\chapter{Before TOC 2}
\Blindtext

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Chap 1}
\Blindtext

\chapter{Chap 2}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image: pdf]

Comment: This solution has made it from my comment to christians answer a while back. The OP also gave the tick to @christian a few minutes ago.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Yeah, just saw that after I added my (correct) answer... Is there a way to delete own (wrong, ...) answers?

Comment: You should see a delete button next to the `edit` button.

Answer (score 0):

Just use both `\pdfbookmark` and `\addcontentsline` like this:

```
% part before generating the TOC

\pdfbookmark[chapter]{\contentsname}{toc} %add TOC to bookmarks
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname} %add TOC to TOC
\tableofcontents

% part after generating the TOC
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work! First [chapter] is unknown and it adds a double entry to the bookmarks

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Ohh, didn't realized the double entries in my bookmarks. Sorry...