# Adding small caps to toc

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, small-caps

I would like to have the title of references and index in small caps in the table of contents, but, as you can see in the following mwe, it's not the case. Is anyone there to help me ?

```
 % book example for classicthesis.sty
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{epigraph} 
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage[tight,french]{minitoc}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc]{../classicthesis} % ,manychapters
%\usepackage[osf]{libertine}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=4cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\newcounter{qcounter}
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\makeindex
\renewcommand\textflush{flushright}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newlength\epitextskip
\pretocmd{\@epitext}{\em}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@epitext}{\em}{}{}
\patchcmd{\epigraph}{\@epitext{#1}\\}{\@epitext{#1}\\[\epitextskip]}{}{}
\makeatother

\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}
\setlength\epitextskip{2ex}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{.8\textwidth}

 \FrenchFootnotes
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{lineno}
 \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
 \AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}}

 \frontmatter
 \begin{document}

 %  \pagestyle{scrheadings}
 %  \manualmark
 %  \markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}

 \pagestyle{scrheadings}

 \tableofcontents

  \clearpage
  ...
  \backmatter
  \bibnewpage 
  { \raggedright 
  \bibliographystyle{apacite} 
  \bibliography{mabiblio}}
  ...
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable so that people can reproduce what you are seeing. If you are using a modified version of `classicthesis` as your code suggests, please tell us about any relevant changes.

Comment: OK. I've just modified my mwe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add the instructions

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\scshape}
```

to the preamble, *after* loading the `classicthesis` package. With this addition in place, the table-of-contents page looks like this (note that there's no entry for the Index since the MWE didn't contain any indexing commands):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{epigraph} 
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage[tight,french]{minitoc}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc]{classicthesis} % ,manychapters
%\usepackage[osf]{libertine}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=4cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\newcounter{qcounter}
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\makeindex
\renewcommand\textflush{flushright}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newlength\epitextskip
\pretocmd{\@epitext}{\em}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@epitext}{\em}{}{}
\patchcmd{\epigraph}{\@epitext{#1}\\}{\@epitext{#1}\\[\epitextskip]}{}{}
\makeatother

\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}
\setlength\epitextskip{2ex}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{.8\textwidth}

 \FrenchFootnotes
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{lineno}
 \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
 \AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\scshape}

 \begin{document}
 \frontmatter

 %  \pagestyle{scrheadings}
 %  \manualmark
 %  \markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}

  \pagestyle{scrheadings}

  \tableofcontents

  \clearpage
  ...
  \mainmatter
  ...
  \clearpage
  \backmatter

  \bibnewpage 
  { \raggedright 
  \bibliographystyle{apacite} 
  \bibliography{mabiblio}}
  ...
  \end{document}
```

Comment: It works ! Thanks. It works also for my index that I didn't mention in the MWE. But do you know why the table of contents indicates a wrong page number ? When I click on the index page number (235), the page number 237 appears.

Comment: @domi - Not having access to your full file, I'm afraid I can't offer a solid diagnosis. Have you tried recompiling two times more, to fully propagate all changes? Does the page numbering issue go away if you uncomment (or remove) the tocloft-related instructions?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Clicking on the index page number leads me to the references page. This is the commands : 
\bibnewpage 
{ \raggedright 
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{mabiblio}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}
\printindex

Comment: @domi - Try inserting the instruction `\clearpage` *before* `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}`.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: @domi - I'm afraid that "it doesn't work" is rather uninformative. Please be more specific. In particular, please indicate if you ran LaTeX *twice* after inserting the additional `\clearpage` instruction.

Comment: Sorry. Yes I do. Do you think I should change the place of `\usepackage{hyperref}` in the preamble ?

Comment: @domi - Does loading `hyperref` last make a difference? Remember that I don't have access to your full file and hence can't provide a complete diagnosis...

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: @domi - Since this problem seems to be unrelated to the matter of this posting, I can only suggest you post a *new query* in which you provide all pertinent information.

Comment: Using `\addcontentsline` with a KOMA class is an indicator for not using the documented and well designed macros. [How to use unnumbered chapters with KOMA-script?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193799) along with options like `bibliography=totoc` or [KOMA book: correct hyperlink to the index?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/208478)

Comment: @Johannes_B - Please consider posting this observation as an additonal answer. Note that the main query of the posting was *not* about `\addcontentsline` at all; that business only  sprang up in comments after I had posted the first answer...

Comment: Thats why this was a comment as well. It wasn't posted to the question because there is no indication of the comand. It is more a reference for future users.

Comment: @Johannes_B - OK.