# KOMA book: correct hyperlink to the index?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, indexing

So I'm using `scrbook`, and in the TOC, the link to the Index goes a bit beyond what it should, like described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172352/correct-hyperlink-to-the-index). Unfortunately the solution described therein is for the `book` class, and it does not work for `scrbook` (*).

Now, I am able to solve the problem (by adding `index=totoc` to the document options, as described in this [other link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65255/link-to-index-in-toc-points-does-not-point-to-index-but-to-whatever-is-right-be)). But I only discovered this latter link after having drawn up a MWE. Further, with my MWE, the other solution proposed in the latter link -- using `\phantomsection` -- does **not** work: TOC's Index link still goes too far. Could anyone help? Thanks.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex

\newcommand{\nist}{%
    NIST%
    \index{National Institute of Standards and Technology}}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
    Lorem ipsum \nist.

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

(*) - In particular, the patch command fails, because `scrbook`'s `\theindex` command definition does not use `twocolumn`.

Comment: Just to make sure, what is your question? In any case, you answer it yourself by telling about the option `index=totoc`. This option (global) should replace those three helper lines (clearpage, phantomsection, toc-line).

Comment: I wanted to understand what is wrong with the MWE -- without using the solution you mention. Because as far as I know, the MWE should work fine without it, but doesn't. The question is why?

Comment: The whole index is an environment internally, before taking its content (the index) it writes a chapter heading. The `phantomsection` is treated like the first content in the environment (after the heading).

Comment: If the option is given, the internals use `addchap` for the index heading. Usually a good idea to use `addchap` for unnumbered stuff that shall appear in the TOC.

Comment: I'll guess i have a bit of spare time coming up, i might add an answer to this.

Comment: I would much appreciate if you did so, because I can't really make sense from your previous two comments :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way is indeed to use `index=totoc`, but why? Let's take a look at the internals.

### Flowing down the levels of implementation

How is `theindex` environment defined in book and scrbook?

book.cls

```
\newenvironment{theindex}
               {\if@twocolumn
                  \@restonecolfalse
                \else
                  \@restonecoltrue
                \fi
                \twocolumn[\@makeschapterhead{\indexname}]%
                \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
                        {\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
                \thispagestyle{plain}\parindent\z@
                \parskip\z@ \@plus .3\p@\relax
                \columnseprule \z@
                \columnsep 35\p@
                \let\item\@idxitem}
               {\if@restonecol\onecolumn\else\clearpage\fi}
```

scrbook.cls

```
\newenvironment{theindex}{%
  \if@twocolumn
    \@restonecolfalse
  \else
    \@restonecoltrue
  \fi
  \columnseprule \z@
  \columnsep 35\p@
  \setchapterpreamble{\index@preamble}%
  \idx@heading%
  \thispagestyle{\indexpagestyle}\parindent\z@
  \setlength{\parskip}{\z@ \@plus .3\p@}%
  \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ \@plus 1fil}%
  \let\item\@idxitem
}{%
  \if@restonecol\onecolumn\else\clearpage\fi
}
```

As you can see, both do basically the same. Checking for
one/two-columnmode, setting the headers, changing the parskip and
-indent. What standard book does was explained by Heiko before:

> [It] suffers from a side effect of the optional argument of
>   `\twocolumn`. The title in the optional argument is put at the top
>   of page in one-column mode, but the current contents of the page
>   (anchor setting) is stalled and is added after the title in
>   two-column mode.

KOMA on the other hand does `\idx@heading` which is defined as:

```
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi%
  \twocolumn[%
    \@chaptertolistsfalse
                  \idx@@heading{\indexname}]%
  \@mkboth{\MakeMarkcase{\indexname}}{\MakeMarkcase{\indexname}}%
```

It does the usual check and issues either one page or a double
page. It uses `\twocolumn` with the optional argument as the
standard class does and sets the headers. `\@chaptertolostsfalse`
prevents the chapter heading from going to the list of figures
and list of tables. The next line leads us to this code

```
\KOMA@key{index}{%
  \KOMA@set@ncmdkey{index}{@tempa}{%
    {notoc}{0},{nottotoc}{0},{default}{0},{plainheading}{0},%
    {totoc}{1},{toc}{1},{notnumbered}{1}%
  }{#1}%
  \ifx\FamilyKeyState\FamilyKeyStateProcessed
    \ifcase \@tempa\relax
      \renewcommand*{\idx@@heading}{%
      \chapter*
      }%
    \or
      \renewcommand*{\idx@@heading}{%
      \addchap
      }%
    \fi
  \fi
}
```

If no value was given to `index`, scrbook uses `\chapter*` just
like the standard book (and also if `notoc` and similar values
were given). If you explicitely decided that the index should go
to the toc, `addchap` is used. `addchap` calls `\@addchap` which
calls `\addchaptertocentry` calling `addtocentrydefault`
calling `tocbasic@addxcontentsline` which finally calls the
ususal `\addcontentsline` in `tocbasic.sty`. All this still
happens within the optional argument of `twocolumn`.

As you can see, Markus Kohm accounted for nearly every possible
situation. Everything is designed in a way, that one change leads
to a constant change in the whole document. All mechanisms are
shared by the commands.

To sum it up, having a look into the KOMA-script documentation once 
in a while can save you some trouble searching for a hack.

```
\documentclass[oneside
,index=totoc
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex

\newcommand{\nist}{%
    NIST%
    \index{National Institute of Standards and
    Technology}
}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum \nist.

%\cleardoublepage
%\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: @lockstep Thanks for commenting those lines out. But where is your answer gone?

Comment: I deleted it because `idxlayout` actually isn't needed to solve OP's problem. (Altough my package is useful in other situations, e.g. for three-column indexes.)

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I delayed accepting it because it still left me confused, but I now see that that is due to my own (lack of) TeX knowledge. Thus, I'll accept it and go searching for the (a?) TeX book...

Comment: @wmnorth I can understand that this is confusing, but the good news is: You don't have to understand it. All you need to know, is `index=totoc` which is explained in the documentation. What happens in the background ... Who gives a rats a\*s\*s ;-p

Comment: Or to put it another way, it's nice to know how an internal combustion engine works, but the important part is to get to work on time in the morning. You need to know how to drive the car.

Comment: @Johannes_B That's a perfectly valid point, but consider this: we don't use cars for their "expressive power". We use them to get from one location to another, in one piece; there's not a lot of variation. And you indeed don't need to know how internal combustion engines work in order to do that.

With systems like (La)TeX, there's a point when you have to do things which are so specific, that it actually pays off to know the internals (even if only slightly). And given some of the things I find myself doing as of late, I suspect I'm quickly approaching that point :)

Comment: Besides as the proverb that Fred Brooks quotes in his "The Mythical Man-Month": «A good workman is known by his tools». When the tools are complex enough (and important enough), I suspect we could change that to: A good workman is known by *the mastery of* his tools. ;-)

Comment: It is really great that you want to know the internals better. Once you know what is going on *under the hood* you are able to fix more and more problems yourself. But i would recommend to take a look at `classes.dtx`, the documented implementation of the standard classes. KOMA is far to advanced and complicated to start with. But you will get there ;-)

Comment: Next thing to look at could be `texdoc source2e` the documented implementation of the kernel features. There is history in there. 20 year old comments on 25 old bugs.