# How can I remove free space before appendix chapter title in my table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, numbering

I have three glossaries in my LaTeX file.

- Abkürzungsverzeichnis (abbreviation glossary) - that is a chapter in appendix, I use this code to generate my abbreviation glossary:

  ```
  \chapter{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
  \begin{acronym}[Bash]
  \acro{aPaaS}{Application Platform as a Service}
  \end{acronym}
  ```
- Abbildungsverzeichnis (figure glossary) - here I use

  ```
  \listoffigures
  ```
- Literaturverzeichnis (bibliography) - here I use

  ```
  \bibliography{file}{}
  ```

And this is what I've got in my table of contents:
[image]

I don't like the 'A', so I have removed it with

```
    \setcounter{chapter}{-1}
    \chapter{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
```

Then I've got this:
[image]

Do you have any ideas how I can remove the free space before 'Abkürzungsverzeichnis'?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you should have gone with `\addchap{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}`?

Comment: And: Welcome to TeX.SX! Note that ideally questions contain an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that allows us to reproduce your problem with as few lines of code as possible. Often the solutions depend on the document class and the packages you use as well as other settings you have in your document. From the code snippet you have shown us so far we can only guess some of these (I guess you use a KOMA class for example so I suggested `\addchap`, but I can't check if it works). If we have an MWE we can also check that our suggestions really work for your setup.

Comment: `\addchap{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}`  works perfect! Exactly what I wanted, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want an unnumbered chapter to appear in the toc and you use a KOMA class, you should use `\addchap`

```
\addchap{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
```

Note that the `\setcounter{chapter}{-1}` is no longer necessary. See also [How to use unnumbered chapters with KOMA-script?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193767/35864)