# list of tables heading is somehow in header when I compile

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I am having bit difficulty with this one. I am making a short (10 page) report for Univercity, and somehow the name of the list of figures (in my language Töfluskrá) is in the header, two chapters in the documents (given that I haven't started the first chapter).

I have tried this

```
\begin{document}
  \begingroup
  \pagestyle{plain}
  \maketitle
  \tableofcontents
  \listoffigures
  \listoftables
  \endgroup
```

Which doesn't help me at all.
Here is the build of the document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, BCOR=10mm]{scrbook}
%\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
%\usepackage{enumerate,color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
% \usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
%\usepackage[sf,normalsize]{subfigure}
\usepackage[format=plain,labelformat=simple,labelsep=colon]{caption}
%\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Myndir/} }
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{heimild.bib}
\author{Ólafur Víðir Guðbjargarson}
\title{Keyrsla vindmylluver í raforkukerfi}

\begin{document}
  \begingroup
  \pagestyle{plain}
  \maketitle
  \tableofcontents
  \listoffigures
  \listoftables
  \endgroup
  \chapter*{Inngangur}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Inngangur}

  
  
  \chapter*{Aðferðir}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Aðferðir}
```

[image]

I am not seeing my error and  I am not finding anything useful off the internet (yet).

I would love the heading to say Aðferð (Method), worst case just skip the header.

To the top... seriously not figuring this out.

Comment: Try `\clearpage` after `\endgroup`? Not sure if that is the correct `page` command but might help

Comment: Unfortunally not helping.... this si just stuck there :/

Comment: It's because you're using `\chapter*`, try [How to use unnumbered chapters with KOMA-script?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193767/106162)

Comment: `\tablewofcontents` writes to the header `\chapter*` does not. You might want to manually reset the headers using `\markboth{}{}` after `\chapter*`

Comment: @DaiBowen this is actually helping a lot. This is probably the answer I am looking for. Thank you.